# Is there any difference between how and that?

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference between "how" and "that" in the following sentences?

1. It’s a funny thing how most people that meditate don’t use the word
   meditate.
2. It’s a funny thing that most people that meditate don’t use the word
   meditate.

Answer (score 1):

They have the same meaning; 'how' is less formal here.

[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/and+how) classifies the 'that' sense of 'how' (example (2) below) under 'conjunction', though 'complementiser' is more accurate.

The old fashioned / dialect 'as how' would work only with sense (2):

> **how**
>
> conj.
>
> 1. The manner or way in which: *forgot how it was done*.
> 2. That: *I told them how I had once been bitten by a snake*.
> 3. In whatever way or manner; however: *Cook it how you please*.

Where sense (1) is available, it is the default, so 'I told them how I'd solved the problem with the boiler' would be assumed to mean 'I explained to them the way in which I'd solved the problem with the boiler'.